# Connect C# application with Remote machine using SSH

Tags: c#

Hi, 
I am trying to build an application using C#.

The application will connect to a remote machine using ssh or similar way.

For example, It will connect to the remote machine and get the list of running process from that process to a text file in my local machine.

Is there any easy way I can do it. I looked into sharshh and it looks old and almost no documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the [SSH.Net library on Codeplex](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/documentation).

Using it is quite straight forward, but you may want to adjust the command that displays running process as needed to fit your scenario:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("host", "username", "password"))
{
  client.Connect();
  var cmd = client.RunCommand("ps -ef");
  File.WriteAllText("your-process-file.txt", cmd.Result);
  client.Disconnect();
}
```